# Spring LDAP Transactions

Tags: spring, transactions, ldap

I´m new in this little world, and I´m trying to develope a Spring Ldap Transaction and I have serious problems with the Spring bean creation.

I have this config XML file:

```
<bean id="ldapContextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://localhost:10389" />
    <property name="base" value="dc=***,dc=com" />
    <property name="authenticationSource" ref="authenticationSource" />
    <property name="pooled" value="false" />
    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="500" />
            <entry key="java.naming.referral" value="follow" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationSource"
    class="org.springframework.ldap.authentication.DefaultValuesAuthenticationSourceDecorator">
    <property name="target" ref="springSecurityAuthenticationSource" />
    <property name="defaultUser" value="uid=admin,ou=system" />
    <property name="defaultPassword" value="secret" />
</bean>

<bean id="springSecurityAuthenticationSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.SpringSecurityAuthenticationSource" />

<bean id="ldapTransactionContextSource"
    class="org.springframework.ldap.transaction.compensating.manager.TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapContextSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapTransactionContextSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.ldap.transaction.compensating.manager.ContextSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="contextSource" ref="ldapTransactionContextSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDaoTarget" class="com.***.daos.UserDao">
    <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDao"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="target" ref="userDaoTarget" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I have problems when the "userDaoTarget" bean is created because it trows this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
```

Finaly my UserDao.class is the next code:

```
public class UserDao extends CommonDao implements ICommonDao<User> {

    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public void setLdapTemplate(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
        this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with the bean creation? I think that the code is correct but i dont know what happens...

Thanks all for your time

Comment: you are missig `org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException` class in your lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Spring dependencies do you have on your classpath? Specifically, do you have the

```
org.springframework.beans-<version>.jar
```

artifact?

Comment: Sorry for delay in my answer but i was out of my country. The dependencies i have in the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

This are the dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```